# get_the_category returns empty on 1 of 2 languages in WPML

Tags: php, wordpress, wpml

People, help out.

We installed WPML, translated everything including categories.
Now for a post in English I can get categories via `get_the_category()`, but for a post in Russian `get_the_category()` returns an empty array.

[image: RU version]

[image: ON EN version array not empty]

Answer (score 1):

```
$category = get_the_category($post->ID);
$cat = wp_get_post_categories($post->ID);
$categories = apply_filters( 'wpml_object_id',  $cat[0], 'category', TRUE  );
$category = get_category($categories);
```